# After high traffic Cassandra WriteTimeoutException

Tags: python-2.7, uwsgi, cassandra-2.0

I'm experimenting with cassandra to use it for storing tracking data. I process get requests (300 req/sec) with tracking information through django with uwsgi on nginx. The django application writes to cassandra (single cluster with 3 RF) directly. For this im taking the cassandra-driver (2.5.0).

After restarting all relevant services the whole thing works for about two hours. Then the server goes down and produces a server error 500.

Currently i don't know where the bottleneck is.
Syslog show normal I/O activity on my system also CPU is just used by 32%.

I'm working primarily with counters. My tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rollup_hour_counter (
  name text,
  player_id text,
  hour timestamp,
  "count" counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name, player_id), hour)
)
```

My code to write into cassandra looks like this:

```
rows = session.execute('UPDATE rollup_hour_counter '
                           'SET count = count + 1'
                           'WHERE player_id=\'%s\' AND hour=\'%s:00:00\' AND name = \'name\'' % (player_uuid, date_now_hour))
```

I did some research on the errors in the log files.

uwsgi logs show:

> Thu Apr 16 07:44:04 2015 -
>   uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe
>   [core/writer.c line 296] during GET
>   /t/i/7bcdd5e185fd4608b0d3c3451f5ec56a/ (146.58.126.229)

cassandra log shows:

> WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-12] 2015-04-16 07:44:50,424 AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-12,5,main]: {}
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2174) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_76]
>   Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.CounterMutation.grabCounterLocks(CounterMutation.java:146) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.CounterMutation.apply(CounterMutation.java:122) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CounterMutation.apply(CounterMutation.java:122) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$8.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1147) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2171) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
>           ... 4 common frames omitted

nginx logs show:

> 2015/04/16 07:43:57 [error] 2111#0: *268738 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 82.115.124.102, server: server.someservice.com, request: "GET
>   [...] HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/track.sock", host: "server2.someotherservice.com",
>   referrer: "[..]"

So first I thought that the uwsgi processes and sockets were responsible. I added some worker processes increased buffer size but no help.

Second i tuned some cassandra settings but no help:

My cassandra settings look like this:

```
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data

commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:

    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"
concurrent_reads: 96
concurrent_writes: 96
concurrent_counter_writes: 96
file_cache_size_in_mb: 1512
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
memtable_flush_writers: 96
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: localhost
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
rpc_min_threads: 60
rpc_max_threads: 96
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
memtable_flush_after_mins: 60
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
    # require_client_auth: false
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    # require_client_auth: false
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    # truststore: conf/.truststore
    # truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
```

Does someone have an idea where the bottleneck is?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty tame workload. I'm not sure why you would be getting write timeouts. One thing to look for: are your Cassandra nodes experiencing high GC pressure (check pauses in gc log - especially on the other nodes, at times correlating with the WriteTimeout).
Also, in the event of WriteTimeout, you need to make sure you're handling the exception on the client side (note that "what to do" might be tricky because retrying a counter update could result in double counting).

Comment: Why other nodes ? Isn't the whole point of Cassandra is to prevent slow nodes from slowing other nodes down ?